# OAuth callback in a jsf app

Tags: java, jsf, oauth

At some point in this jsf web application, the current user is prompted to identify with Twitter via OAuth.

After the user identified on Twitter the OAUth callback url redirects to my app:

http://www.myJsfApp.com/successAuth.xhtml

But of course without a session id this successAuth.xhtml is not connected to the user session. The page is just the "raw" xhtml file (with all its  tags) and no html.

How can I make this callback url to link back to the current session?

Comment: for start : don't you want to redirect your user to *http://www.myJsfApp.com/successAuth.jsf* (*jsf* suffix)

Comment: uhh dunno. The address bar of my app shows xhtml extensions. For example: http://localhost:8080/myApp/faces/index.xhtml;jsessionid=4566F5BB481F9CFB0D2EA588061F2BF7

Comment: ok, so your `FacesServlet` mapped to `faces/` so add the `faces/` prefix to your page *myJsfApp.com/faces/successAuth.xhtml*  , Also you might consider creating a `Filter` map it to `successAuth.jsf` and continue from there... (check this as well http://balusc.blogspot.co.il/2007/03/user-session-filter.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *But of course without a session id this successAuth.xhtml is not connected to the user session.*

If your servletcontainer supports URL rewriting (by default, they all do), then you can just pass the session ID as URL path fragment.

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) externalContext.getSession();
String callbackURL = "http://www.myJsfApp.com/successAuth.xhtml;jsessionid=" + session.getId();
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [socialauth - can you use same session across a redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307702/socialauth-can-you-use-same-session-across-a-redirect/12310858#12310858)

---

> *The page is just the "raw" xhtml file (with all its tags) and no html.*

That will happen when the `FacesServlet` isn't been invoked. The request URL must match the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet` in order to invoke it. So, if you have configured it to listen on for example `/faces/*` URLs, then you should obviously change the URL to `faces/successAuth.xhtml`.

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) externalContext.getSession();
String callbackURL = "http://www.myJsfApp.com/faces/successAuth.xhtml;jsessionid=" + session.getId();
// ...
```

Alternatively, you can also just map the `FacesServlet` on `*.xhtml`, this way you never need to fiddle with virtual URLs.

#### See also:

- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why)